# Call an Jquery Ajax only after several fields have been edited in a Data table row

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, razor

I have a table in ASP MVC where a user can make changes to several fields within a row which are dropdown menus. Once the changes are made and user removes focus from that row I want to call AJAX to save changes. My problem is that the AJAX call is made for every single change that is made, so many calls for a single row.

```js
//JQUERY

$(function () {

    $(".payroll").on('change',function (e) {

            var ctrl = $(this).closest('tr');

            var empID = ctrl.find("td:first").html();
            var employeeLine1 = ctrl.find("td:nth-child(2)").html();
            var employeeLine2 = $.trim(ctrl.find("td:nth-child(3) span").html());
            
            updatepayroll(empID, employeeLine1, employeeLine2, ctrl);

    });
 
 updatepayrollReallocation = function (empID, employeeLine1, employeeLine2, ctrl) {

 $.ajax({
  
  //Update changes
  
   });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<tr>
    <td id="payrollID">1</td>
    
 <td>@Html.DropDownListFor(modelItem => item.employeeLine,(SelectList)ViewBag.employeeLineHeaders,
             item.employeeLine, new { @class = "payroll", @data_width = "fit" })
 </td>
 <td>@Html.DropDownListFor(modelItem => item.employeeLine2,(SelectList)ViewBag.employeeLine2Headers,
             item.employeeLine2, new { @class = "payroll", @data_width = "fit" })
 </td>
</tr>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to send callback when any controls inside a row lost its focus, use `focusout` event handling against table row like this (assumed `PayrollGrid` is the `<table>` ID set by `id` attribute):

```
$("#PayrollGrid").on('focusout', 'td', function () {
    $.ajax({
        // do something with AJAX callback
    });
});
```

If you want to trigger AJAX based on focus of `DropDownListFor` helpers, use `payroll` class instead:

```
$("#PayrollGrid").on('focusout', '.payroll', function () {
    $.ajax({
        // do something with AJAX callback
    });
});
```

Also note that you may try to declare `empID`, `employeeLine1`, `employeeLine2` and `ctrl` variables outside the scope, then assign it inside `change` event handling and pass it to AJAX callback when `focusout` event is triggered.

Comment: this helps, the point I was missing is the fact that I can pass 3 parameters to .on() function.